# Why is my Contact Form 7 field validation prohibiting empty entries too?

Tags: wordpress, validation, plugins, contact-form-7

I have a validation added in my functions.php for two fields. These validate that the field can only take letters/numbers and no special characters. It works fine but unfortunately the field 'tussenvoegsel' can not be left empty, which needs to be possible too.

```
// VALIDATIE INPUT FIELDS (GEEN CIJFERS MOGELIJK ALS INPUT)
add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_text', 'alphanumeric_validation_filter', 20, 2 );
add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_text*', 'alphanumeric_validation_filter', 20, 2 );

function alphanumeric_validation_filter( $result, $tag ) {
    $tag = new WPCF7_Shortcode( $tag );
    
    if ( 'familienaam' == $tag->name ) {
        $name_of_the_input = isset( $_POST['familienaam'] ) ? trim( $_POST['familienaam'] ) : '';
        
        if ( !preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/',$name_of_the_input) ) {
            $result->invalidate( $tag, "Alleen letters zijn toegestaan." );
        }
    }
    
    if ( 'tussenvoegsel' == $tag->name ) {
        $name_of_the_input = isset( $_POST['tussenvoegsel'] ) ? trim( $_POST['tussenvoegsel'] ) : '';
        
        if ( !preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/',$name_of_the_input) ) {
            $result->invalidate( $tag, "Alleen letters zijn toegestaan." );
        }
    }
    
    return $result;
}
```

Which is strange as the entry in the plugin of 'tussenvoegsel' doesn't have an *.
What can I add to keep the 'tussenvoegel' entry still optional even though I needs to validate too.

```
[text tussenvoegsel placeholder "voorvoegsel"]
[text* familienaam placeholder "Achternaam"]
```

Comment: Why do you have a second filter wpcf7_validate_text* ? That should be causing an error. Try commenting it out, and checking validation again.

Comment: I've commented out "wpcf7_validate_text". Validation for 'familienaam' works correct now and I can leave 'tussenvoegsel' optionally empty too. But the validation for 'tussenvoegsel' is not working currently as I can still place special characters.

If I comment out the other one "wpcf7_validate_text*" then the 'tussenvoegsel' field can not be kept empty anymore and the validation for 'familienaam' does not work.

Comment: The one with wpcf7_validate_text* is the one to comment out. Anyway, if it can be empty now, it is the validation code that is not correct, let me review it

Comment: https://contactform7.com/2015/03/28/custom-validation/ wpcf7_validate_text* is a valid hook after all. I am writing the answer for you now, give me a few minutesd

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know if it works or what happens? I can adjust it, but don't have a site with CF7 at hand right now to test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your function, you're validating the CF7 Fields, but you're not checking to see if the field is required or not.  With that being the case, it will always run your funciton through a validation filter, and require that the input is alphanumeric whether the field is required or not.

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_text', 'alphanumeric_validation_filter', 20, 2 );
add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_text*', 'alphanumeric_validation_filter', 20, 2 );

function alphanumeric_validation_filter( $result, $tag ) {
    $tag = new WPCF7_Shortcode( $tag );

    if ( 'familienaam' === $tag->name ) {
        $name_of_the_input = isset( $_POST['familienaam'] ) ? trim( $_POST['familienaam'] ) : '';
        // Check if the field is empty or required.
        if ( ! empty( $name_of_the_input ) || $tag->is_required() ) {
            if ( !preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $name_of_the_input ) ) {
                $result->invalidate( $tag, 'Alleen letters zijn toegestaan.' );
            }
        }
    }
    
    if ( 'tussenvoegsel' === $tag->name ) {
        $name_of_the_input = isset( $_POST['tussenvoegsel'] ) ? trim( $_POST['tussenvoegsel'] ) : '';
        // Check if the field is empty or required.
        if ( ! empty( $name_of_the_input ) || $tag->is_required() ) {
            if ( ! preg_match( '/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $name_of_the_input ) ) {
                $result->invalidate( $tag, 'Alleen letters zijn toegestaan.' );
            }
        }
    }
    
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: I tested this with a default contact form 7. You still need to apply_filters

Comment: See - https://snipboard.io/Zinud0.jpg and https://snipboard.io/OrEpvF.jpg for examples of output.

Comment: You're right, it works as intended now. Thank you for your help! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Using the official docs for custom validation here https://contactform7.com/2015/03/28/custom-validation/

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_text', 'alphanumeric_validation_filter', 20, 2 );
add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_text*', 'alphanumeric_validation_filter', 20, 2 );
    
function alphanumeric_validation_filter( $result, $tag ) {
    
        if ( 'familienaam' == $tag->name ) {
         $familienaam= isset( $_POST['familienaam'] ) ? trim( $_POST['familienaam'] ) : '';
        
            if ( !ctype_alnum( $familienaam) ) {
               $result->invalidate( $tag, "Alleen letters zijn toegestaan." );
            }
        }
        
        if ( 'tussenvoegsel' == $tag->name ) {
            $tussenvoegsel = isset( $_POST['tussenvoegsel'] ) ? trim( $_POST['tussenvoegsel'] ) : '';
        
             if ( !ctype_alnum( $tussenvoegsel ) ) {
                $result->invalidate( $tag, "Alleen letters zijn toegestaan." );
             }
         }
    
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: The validation works for both fields now so that is correct :) The only problem is still that the 'tussenvoegsel' field can not be kept empty.

Comment: Strange... that is not being done in the code above. What if you try commenting out the filter with the * and trying again if all validation plus being able to leave empty works?

Comment: Also, what error message does it give for the empty, "Alleen letters zijn toegestaan." or a different one?

Comment: Your code above currently works best as it validates correct for both, I only can't keep that field empty. If I comment out the one with *, it will not validate the 'familienaam' field anymore. Seems that both add filters are required. I'm not actually seeing the message, just an icon indicating an error. https://ibb.co/H7ZbRK3

Comment: Tami, tank you for your help as well! I appreciate it a lot :)